# CakePHP: media views for mp3 files streamed with flash player

Tags: file, cakephp, view, streaming, media

I have a page with a audio flash player that streams several mp3 files. This player uses an XML file that has the path of all those files, which are in a **audio** folder in the webroot directory.

What I don't like is that it's pretty easy for a user to get to the XML file (which is also in the webroot directory) and see the paths of the mp3 files, and then download them instead of just using the flash player.

I've seen that CakePHP has something called **Media Views**, where you can set a folder outside the webroot and place your files there, so users can't freely access them. The explanation in Cake's website (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1094/Media-Views) is focused on files to download, but I would like to know if I can use the Media Views to stream my mp3 files with the audio player without making them downloadable by the users. OR if there's any other alternative without Media Views that would work as well :)

Thanks so much in advance!

**CLARIFICATION**

This is the code that I'm using that I would like to change:

**- In my controller:**

```
function index() {}
```

**- In my view (index.ctp):**

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=/audios/01 Track 01.mp3" src="audio-player.swf"></embed>
```

=>How can I change that using Media Views so that my mp3 file is in a folder app/audios instead of app/webroot/audios?

**THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

**- In my controller (streams_controller.php):**

```
function index() {}

function getFile() {

    $this->view = 'Media';

    $params = array(
                    'id' => '01 Track 01.mp3',
                    'name' => '01 Track 01',
                    'download' => false,
                    'extension' => 'mp3',
                    'path' => APP . 'audios' . DS,
                    'cache' => true
                    );

    $this->set($params);
}
```

**- In my view (index.ctp):**

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=/streams/getFile" src="audio-player.swf"></embed>
```

STILL NO LUCK! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Media view seems to be what you need here. It will allow you to move the mp3 outside the webroot.
Cake will send headers to force the download only if you pass true for the 'download' key in options.

Just set if to false and it might work.

Comment: I've tried with 'false' in the download key but the download dialog still appears, only that asking to download the page instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think, by default, the user will be able to download the file either way, from a webroot file path or from a /controller/action path.

But this is easy to overcome, with a couple of security implementations.

NOTE: in my opinion, if you're using Authorization of some sort, you should hash based on their ['User']['id'] instead of their IP

```
/**
* Action to download special assets
* example link to download <?php echo $this->Html->link('Link Text', array('action' => 'download', Security::hash('filedownloadsalt'.date('d').env('REMOTE_ADDR')), $filename), array('escape' => false)); ?>
* example URL to download <?php echo $this->Html->url(array('action' => 'download', Security::hash('filedownloadsalt'.date('d').env('REMOTE_ADDR')), $filename)); ?>
* @param string $hash
* @param string $filename
*/
function download($hash=null, $filename=null) {
    // check to ensure that the input hash is specific to this user and created today
    if (Security::hash('filedownloadsalt'.date('d').env('REMOTE_ADDR'))!=$hash) {
        $this->Session->setFlash("Sorry, you are not allowed access to this asset");
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'failure'));
    }
    // check to ensure referrer URL is on this domain
    if (strpos(env('HTTP_REFERER'), env('HTTP_HOST'))===false) {
        $this->Session->setFlash("Sorry, you must access this asset from within my site, not directly");
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'failure'));
    }
    // now get the asset
    $filenameParts = explode('.', $filename);
    $filenameExt = array_pop($filenameParts);
    $filenameBase = implode('.', $filenameParts);
    $this->view = 'Media';
    $params = array(
        'id' => $filename,
        'name' => $filenameBase,
        'download' => true,
        'extension' => strtolower($filenameExt),
        'path' => APP . 'files' . DS,   // don't forget terminal 'DS'
        'cache' => true,
        );
    $this->set($params);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but it looks like it works if I want to place files in a folder for download. I just want the flash player to find them in another folder...

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp 3x media files farce to download

if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
     $data = $this->request->data;

```
 // $file_name= 'test.mp4';
 $file_name = $data['files'];
 $this->viewClass = 'Media';

  $file_path = WWW_ROOT . 'files/video/' . DS . $file_name;
 //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download
 $this->response->file($file_path, array(
    'download' => true,
    'name' => $file_name,
 ));
 return $this->response;

 exit;
}
```